# Athena Connection with R

Tags: r, amazon-athena, rjdbc

I am new to Athena. I want to connect this with R

```
Sys.getenv()
    URL <- 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC42_2.0.14.jar'
fil <- basename(URL)
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)

drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver", fil, identifier.quote="'")
```

This is the error message

```
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : 
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Referred this article
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-amazon-athena/

```
   con <- jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(drv, 'jdbc:awsathena://athena.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443/',
                                   s3_staging_dir="s3://aws-athena-query-results-ap-south-1-region/",
                                   user=("xxx"),
                                   password=("xxx"))
```

Need help really struggling from two days

Thanks in advance. I downloaded jar files and java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a newer driver version and the driver is now developed by simba and therefore the driver class name has changed.

The driver class is now `com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver`.

You may also want to check out [AWR.Athena](https://github.com/nfultz/AWR.Athena) - A nice R package to interact with Athena.

Comment: The latest driver is 2.0.14 - https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.14/AthenaJDBC42_2.0.14.jar

Comment: drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver", fil, identifier.quote="'") this throws an error like Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : 
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having difficulty with the JDBC drivers for Athena you could always try: [RAthena](https://dyfanjones.github.io/RAthena/) or [noctua](https://dyfanjones.github.io/noctua/). These two packages opt in using AWS SDK to make the connection to AWS Athena.

`RAthena` uses [Python boto3 sdk](https://github.com/boto/boto3) (similar to [pyathena](https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthena)), through [reticulate](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate).

`noctua` uses [R paws sdk](https://github.com/paws-r/paws).

Code Example:

```
library(DBI)

# connect to AWS
# using ~/.aws/credentials to store aws credentials
con <- dbConnect(RAthena::athena(),
                 s3_staging_dir = "s3://mybucket/")

# upload some data into aws athena
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)

# query iris in aws athena
dbGetQuery(con, "select * from iris")
```

**NOTE:** `noctua` works extactly the same way as code example above but instead the driver is: `noctua::athena()`